# How to Add dynamic image on body of Email using phpmail

Tags: php

I am creating a email service which send different image to different person using phpmail.I can send mail and attachment as i require but when it comes to dynamically adding embedded image in body of mail.
I wont be able to achieve success.

```
<?php

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

// multiple recipients
$to = $arr['Contact.Email']; // note the comma

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on     errors, which we need to catch

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
try{
  $mail->SetFrom($arr['Contact.Email'], 'First Last');
  $mail->AddAddress($arr['Contact.Email'], 'John Doe');
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test';

  $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($arr['ContactId'].'.png', 'my-attach');

  $mail->Body = 'Your <b>HTML</b> with an embedded Image: <img src=cid:my-attach\'> Here is an image!';

  $mail->AddAttachment($arr['ContactId'].".png"); // this is a regular attachment (Not inline)

  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK<p></p>\n";
} 

catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
}

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
?>
```

I can embed one image but when i try to send different image for different user i get an error.I searched everywhere but i did not get any satisfactorily answer.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `i get an error` - What error?

Comment: Get an error means it wont send email in which image is in mail body.image is just an attachment.

Comment: Again: What error? What is the exact text of the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error at:

```
$mail->Body = 'Your <b>HTML</b> with an embedded Image: <img src=cid:my-attach\'> Here is an image!';
```

You need to skip the **\'** after attach.

You also need to set the message to html format by adding:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Read more about embedding images in the docs here: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial

Comment: I tried that as well but result is same..Body of email doesnot contain image.image is just an attachment.

Comment: I just like to send email but emailbody image for each and evry user should be deifferent.

Comment: In the documentation there are 3 arguments for the function AddEmbeddedImage. You only have 2 in your code. Correct your code so that it looks like the embedded image example in the docs. Also try to remove the "AddAttachment" line as that contains the same image. This might cause the problem as well. You do not need to attach the image as well as displaying it inline?

Comment: @VIRUS I´m glad to help. Please mark the question as answered by clicking the V.